# Доработать RewriteRule, подкорректировать обработку корневой дирректории /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Цель в том, чтобы статику ангуляра вынести в отдельную папку, но при этом открывать в корне

1) Исключить из обработки существующие физически файлы и папки

```
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

2) Не существующие перенаправить в папку со статикой

```
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /papka/$1
```

3) Все запросы в этой папке к несуществующим в ней файлам отправить на index.html

```
    RewriteRule ^ papka/index.html
```

Так все работает, но если вход произведен с корня сайта, то первое правило его тоже считает существующей директорией и не открывает в каталоге со статикой. Помогите добавить исключение для корневой директории.

И еще, я чувствую, что где-то логика хромает, если есть замечания, то это тоже важно.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все заработало как хотелось, методом тыка в самый верх добавил:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
```